# LilyPond: modifying woodwind diagrams

Tags: fingering, lilypond, engraving, woodwinds, lily-scheme

Regarding woodwind diagram in LilyPond such as:

```
\markup {
\center-column {
\override #'(size . 0.7) {
\woodwind-diagram #'flute  #'((cc . (oneF two three four five six))
                             (lh . ())
                             (rh . ())) }}}
```

... which results in:
[image: flute fingering diagram 123|456]

Is it possible to change the diagram somehow to get something like:
[image: flute fingering diagram with alteration Y|123|456]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create new patterns using Scheme:

> Creating new diagrams is possible, although this will require Scheme ability and may not be accessible to all users. The patterns for the diagrams are in ‘scm/define-woodwind-diagrams.scm’ and ‘scm/display-woodwind-diagrams.scm’.

Source: https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/source/Documentation/notation/woodwind-diagrams.html

The simplest one might be to make a copy of the whistle scheme file and modify it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

My friend assist me to defined those Lilybin lines, in order to add additional grafical to wood-wind diagram:

```
    \version "2.22.1"

% LilyBin
#(define-markup-command
  (woodwind-diagram-x layout props 
    instrument user-draw-commands)
  (symbol? list?)
  #:properties ((upper-hole1 #f)
                (size 1)
                (thickness 0.1)
                (graphical #t))
  (let* ((ww-diagram
          (interpret-markup layout props
            (make-woodwind-diagram-markup
             instrument user-draw-commands)))
         (hole-circle
          (make-circle-stencil size thickness upper-hole1))
         (midline
          (make-line-stencil (* thickness 2) (* -0.80 size) 0 (* 0.80 size) 0))
         (upper-circle-and-midline
          (ly:stencil-combine-at-edge hole-circle Y DOWN midline (* 0.80 size))))
    (ly:stencil-combine-at-edge
     upper-circle-and-midline Y DOWN ww-diagram (* 0.80 size))
    ))

\markup {
  \center-column {
  \override #'(upper-hole1 . #f)
    \override #'(size . 0.7) {
      \woodwind-diagram-x #'flute
      #'((cc . (oneF two three four five six))
         (lh . ())
         (rh . ()))
    }
  }
}
```

That works.
Thanks a lot guys